# Digital Ocean + Godaddy Domain ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: digital-ocean, resolve, domain-name

I am receiving the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. I have setup a Digital Ocean (DO) droplet and set the DO ns1. ns2. ns3.digitalocean.com nameservers at Godaddy.

Created an A records for mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com and both pointed to droplet's IP.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the DNS is propagating in https://whatsmydns.net. If it's propagating to your Digitalocean IP, then clear your browser cache else try in another network.